# Does memory leak created by malloc remains forever?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I am learning to code in C. I came across the term 'memory leak'. So, I want to ask, if I wrote a simple program in C, in which malloc() is used and if I didn't free it (though I know freeing the dynamically allocated memory is a good programming practice).
Will that memory leak would be there in the system permanently?
Will the OS never use that memory again as it is sort of lost maybe?

Just consider the case where small amount of memory(100 bytes or so) is allocated, which we do while practicing.
I'm asking this because I'm running the same program multiple times for debugging, are those memory leaks harmful?

Or the OS detects the memory leak and restore it?

Any help regarding the above and related topics is appreciated.

Comment: A sane OS will clean up after the leaky program after it is terminated. That is, only the memory which "belongs" to the program can leak. But once there is no process anymore, there is no memory which belongs to it.

Comment: The memory is freed when your app terminates. You should not leave the memory leaks, though - getting in the habit of always cleaning up after yourself is better, so you don't get sloppy later when it matters. Learn proper programming habits, and use them every time.

Comment: Depends on the OS; any modern operating system will clean up leaked memory once a program terminates, but some older or oddball systems may not.  Memory leaks are more of an issue for programs that run a long time (days, weeks, or months continuously) - if you're allocating but never freeing memory, then eventually you'll exhaust the memory pool for that program.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

General-purpose operating systems are designed to protect against all sorts of issues caused by misbehaving programs. That includes managing memory. The operating system maintains its own records about what memory has been provided to each process, and it reclaims that memory when the process terminates (and no other process is using it, as occurs with various shared memory).

Special-purpose “embedded” operating systems might not provide this function.

Comment: Thank you very much!